# Proving convergence of sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've tried to prove the following proposition but my attemps have failed:

Given sequences $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ such as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n}^{2}+b_{n}^{2}+a_{n}b_{n})=0$ then $a_{n},b_{n}$ are convergence to zero.

I tried it using the convergence definition and as a consequence I have:
$|a_{n}b_{n}|<|a_{n}^{2}+b_{n}^{2}+a_{n}b_{n}|<\epsilon,$ so $a_nb_n$ converges to $0,$ but this happend only if that sequence is positive or zero. I would like to prove that to apply algebra of limits and conclude the desired convergence.

Could you help me?

I'd appreciate any kind of help to solve this exercise.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you mean the product $a_{n}b_{n}$ converges to $0$?  Or that each sequence $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ must converge to $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outline: We have
 $$2(a_n^2+b_n^2 +a_nb_n)=a_n^2+b_n^2+(a_n+b_n)^2.$$

It follows that if $a_n^2+b_n^2+a_nb_n \lt \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$ then $|a_n-0|\lt \epsilon$ and $|b_n-0|\lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Note that $a_n^2+b_n^2+a_nb_n = \left(a_n+\dfrac{b_n}2\right)^2 + \dfrac34 b_n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every one! The answers are very nice. Before to check your solutions I thought using a contradictory argument which, in fact, gives a easy solution to the problem  but the soultions that you provided are too elegant. :)

Thanks again!